# Can someone tell me why this keeps returning degrees instead of meters?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, srid

Can someone tell me why this keeps returning degrees instead of meters? I’m transforming the geometry SRID to 32613, which measures in meters. Thanks

```sql
SELECT storm_date, hail_size_inches, 
       ST_Distance(
         ST_Transform(geom32613, 32613), 
         ST_SetSRID(
           ST_MakePoint(-104.89907, 39.66643), 
           32613)
       ) distance
FROM hail.hail_swaths
WHERE storm_date >= '2021/06/01'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using lat-long coordinates (4326) as if they were in [32613](https://epsg.io/32613).

`ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-104.89907, 39.66643), 32613)` --> replace with   `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-104.89907, 39.66643), 4326),32613);`

Also double check what values are stored in the column `geom32613`. If they are indeed in 32613, there is no need to reproject them

Example for 1 degree, near the central meridian for this projection:

```sql
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-105 40)',32613),
jgtest(>    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-106 40)',32613));
   st_distance
------------------
 85361.8049211818
```

Comment: Thanks. I’m measuring the distance from a MultiPolygon to a Point. I thought this would return the distance from the Point geometry to the closest Polygon in the Multipolygon geometry. Is this an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

Your problem might be somewhere else. `ST_Distance` with two geometries using the SRS 32613 returns the distance in metres:

```
SELECT ST_Distance('SRID=32613;POINT(508654.55672303465 4390740.143711988)',
                   'SRID=32613;POINT(508654.55672303480 4390740.143711988)');

     st_distance      
----------------------
 1.74622982740402e-10
(1 row)
```

It also works using `ST_Transform`

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-104.89910 39.66643)',32613),
    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-104.89907 39.66643)',32613));
   st_distance    
------------------
 2.57321026907276
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bda7184b7f4ae9a7a67409349033a1bb)

Are you perhaps mixing the order of the coordinate pairs? Remember, it is longitude, latitude, not the other way around. If the geometries are correct, please post a WKT literal from both geometries, so that we can reproduce your environment. Another option would be to use `geography` instead of `geometry`, which would automatically return the result in metres, but you would need to transform the geometries encoded in 32613 in a lon/lat coordinate system to make the cast work, such as 4326.

**EDIT**: Read carefully the answer of @JGH - he might have found the real issue. You're probably using the coordinates with a wrong SRS!